# How do I write a script to disconnect all network drives?

Tags: snow-leopard, windows, network

I work in a windows environment with active directory. Just logging out doesn't disconnect (unbind) the network drives. I need something more forceful, and faster than shutting down and restarting. Because if my mac awakes in another network without connection to the windows shares it gives me the spinning beach ball of death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these shares automounted?

You could use AppleScript, or even bash quite effectively to do this using a Log Out Hook (or running manually):

```
tell application "Finder"
    if ((count of disks) > 1) then
        set drives to disks
        repeat with drive in drives
            eject drive
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Great! Works! Is there a parameter I can give to the 'eject' command so it auto-force-disconnects the drives? It asked unjustly for a force disconnect when I ran it.

Comment: @Anton: I'm not sure - there doesn't appear to be anything in Finder's AppleScript Dictionary about this and I've never had to force eject them. Sorry.